# Query to replace a comma in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table with the columns employee, address, city, state and zipcode. I have merged address, city, state, zipcode to a single column 'address' separating each field by comma.

My issue is, if one of the fields is null, an extra comma will be inserted. For example if `city` is null the resulting value will be like `address,,state,zipcode`. I need to remove this extra comma. How to do this? Please help.

Comment: -1: Why would you create a single column with four distinct values in it?

Comment: why are you trying to do this? Usually, it actually makes sense to leave the extra comma so that it's blank (when it should be blank)

Answer (score 15):

You could use a `case when` construct

```
   ... = case when city is null then '' else city + ',' end
```

If the values are already in the database you could replace it this way:

```
   UPDATE tableX SET address= replace(address, ',,', ',')
```

Execute it N times to be sure to cover even the "all fields are null" case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure REPLACE() always replaces all occurrences.  At least, it does in tSQL and MySQL, I'm not sure if it's part of the vanilla SQL standard.

Comment: Yes, but select for example select replace(',,,', ',,', ',') results in ,,

Answer (score 1):

or you can do this manually in php

```
<?php

$str = 'address,,state,zipcode';

$str = preg_replace('/,{2,}/i', ',', $str);
echo $str;

?>
```

I believe you can  do this in your language too

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace('LOKO, , , kkslksl  ',' ',''),',','<>'),'><',''),'<>',',') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replace when you concat your string for insert :

```
REPLACE('address,,state,zipcode', ',,' , ',' )
```